# Массовое удаление и добавление css класса в группе элементов js

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, uikit

Необходимо добавить класс `uk-hidden` для всех элементов с классом `continue_text` и одновременно удалить класс `uk-hidden` во всех элементах с классом `review_show_button`.

Есть конструкция:

```
<li>
  <div>
    <?php echo $item['content']; ?>
      <?php if ($item['continue_text'] ) : ?>
           <a class="review_show_button" data-uk-toggle="{target:'.continue_text ,.review_show_button'}"> Читать полностью </a> 

            <span class="continue_text uk-hidden"><?php echo $item['continue_text']; ?>

            <a class="review_hide_button" data-uk-toggle="{target:'.continue_text,.review_show_button'}"> Свернуть </a>

            </span>

    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>                
</li>
```

используется UIkit. 
`<li>...</li>` — один слайд. Таких слайдов несколько порядка 25

`.review_show_button` — переключает/удаляет `uk-hidden` в элементе с классом  `continue_text`. (показывается полный текст)

`.review_hide_button` — добавляет `uk-hidden` в элементе с классом  `continue_text` и удаляет `uk-hidden` в `<a class="review_show_button">`

Существует также

```
<div><a href="#" class="slidenav-previous" data-uk-slideshow-item="previous"> предыдущий </a> </div>
<div ><a href="#" class="slidenav-next" data-uk-slideshow-item="next" > следующий </a></div>
```

Необходимо, что при каждом нажатии `slidenav-previous` или `slidenav-next` происходило добавление класса `uk-hidden` ко всем элементам на странице с классом `continue_text` и удаление `uk-hidden` у всех элементов на странице с классом `review_show_button`. Добавление/удаление `uk-hidden` должно происходить в случае отсутствия/наличия соответственно у элементов указанных класов. т.е. вероятно должна быть проверка.

P.S. можно было бы сделать все на js, не сипользуя uikiit, но благодаря data-uk-toggle все это работает корректно с изменением высоты виджета. Так как владею js на уровне копипаст, решил просто добавить js, который добавить удалит нужный класс, как описано выше. 
Так как владею js очень плохо сделать код который корректно отрабатывал у меня не получилось. 
Как можно реализовать подобное? Буду благодарен за помощь. Способ реализации неважен, js, jquerry, возможно даже тот же uikit.

Как работает сам виджет-слайдер можно посмотреть тут [https://dizajn-nogtej.taisiavlasova.com/#my-id-03](https://taisiavlasova.com/#my-id-03)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на jquery что то типа этого.

```
  $(".slidenav-previous").click(function(){
    $(".continue_text").toggleClass("uk-hidden");
    $(".review_show_button").toggleClass("uk-hidden");
  })
  $(".slidenav-next").click(function(){
    $(".continue_text").toggleClass("uk-hidden");
    $(".review_show_button").toggleClass("uk-hidden");
  })
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! только toggleClass и так реализуется с помощью uikit. Поменял на  addClass и removeClass и все заработало как нужно.

Comment: Еще вопрос, данный виджет поддерживает пролистывание, свайп влево вправо. Во время свайпа  '<li></li>' получает класс 'uk-slideshow-scroll-forward-out', а следующтй слайд 'uk-slideshow-scroll-forward-in' . Анлалогично происходит и при свайпе назад с '<li></li>'  'uk-slideshow-scroll-backward-out' происходит переход на '<li></li>' 'uk-slideshow-scroll-backward-in'. Эти классы применяются на доли секунды и появляются только в момент пролистывания. Можно ли "прикрутить"  'addClass' и 'removeClass' к этим действиям?

Comment: что к чему прикрутить? ты хочешь при нажатии на кнопку .slidenav-next добавить класс ".uk-slideshow-scroll-forward-out" на текущий слайд и ".uk-slideshow-scroll-forward-in" на следующий и наоборот?

Comment: нет, не совсем так. Хотел чтобы код который Вы написали выполнялся не только при клике на 'review_show_button' и 'review_hide_button', но и при свайпе влево вправо.  Думаю, что Для реализации этого Классы 'uk-slideshow-scroll-backward-out' и др. веротяно мало чем помогут, но как раз они добавляются и удаляются при свайпе по умолчанию в uikit. (где-то в течении пол секунды происходит добавление и удаление). По аналогии с этим я хотел продублировать добавление/удаление класса еще и при свайпе.

Comment: Порылся в js того, как реализовано добавление того самого класса ''uk-slideshow-scroll-backward-out'' в uikit, но так и не смог адаптировать для своей задачи!  Я так понимаю что наряду с .click(function(){ нужно добавить что-то на подобии .swipe(function(){ . Но как точно это должно выглядеть догнать не могу.

Comment: то есть при свайпе влево / вправо в данном виджете нужно чтобы происходило добавление класса uk-hidden ко всем элементам на странице с классом continue_text и удаление uk-hidden у всех элементов на странице с классом review_show_button. . То есть все то же, что и выполняется при нажатии slidenav-previous или slidenav-next